# Golang AWS SDK CreateVirtualMFADevice Print CreateVirtualMFADeviceOutput QRCodePNG

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk

I'm trying to make it easy for users to create their own Virtual MFA device and I get the results from CreateVirtualMFADevice function but I'm lost on how to print the QRCodePNG it self. When I print the results I just get the binary JSON results. Here is my code:

```
                reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
                fmt.Println("Enter name of new virtual device: ")
                user, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
                }
                input := &iam.CreateVirtualMFADeviceInput{
                        VirtualMFADeviceName: aws.String(strings.TrimSpace(user)),
                        //Path:                 aws.String("./QR_Code.png"),
                }
                result, err := svc.CreateVirtualMFADevice(input)
                if err != nil {
                        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
                                switch aerr.Code() {
                                case iam.ErrCodeLimitExceededException:
                                        fmt.Println(iam.ErrCodeLimitExceededException, aerr.Error())
                                case iam.ErrCodeEntityAlreadyExistsException:
                                        fmt.Println(iam.ErrCodeEntityAlreadyExistsException, aerr.Error())
                                case iam.ErrCodeServiceFailureException:
                                        fmt.Println(iam.ErrCodeServiceFailureException, aerr.Error())
default:
                                        fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
                                }
                        } else {
                                // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
                                // Message from an error.
                                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                        }
                        return
                }

fmt.Println(result)
```

Here are the references to the SDK calls: 
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/iam/#IAM.CreateVirtualMFADevice`

This is the output I get from fmt.Println(result)

```
Enter name of new virtual device:
blah
Enter QR code to google authenticator
{
  VirtualMFADevice: {
    Base32StringSeed: <binary> len 64,
    QRCodePNG: <binary> len 1619,
    SerialNumber: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:mfa/blah"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I print out the QR code to the screen?

Comment: It returns the QR code as a PNG in raw bytes. If this is a CLI tool you could write that to a file with a ".png" extension, if this is a web app you can serve those bytes with the mime type "image/png".